# Change the value of a public instance inside an anonymous class' implementation?

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, anonymous-class

Here is an example code for what i am currently doing

```
Class classA{

    public int changeit=1;

    Button obj;

    create(){
        Obj.addlistener(new inputlistener(){
            void touchdown(....){changeit=2;}
        });
    }

    int getvalue(){
        return changeit;
    }

}
```

But `getvalue()` never returns the changed value it always returns `1`.
Please suggest if there is any better way doing it or if I should create a subclass for `inputListener`.

Comment: Can you cut and paste the actual code you're using? This won't compile.

Comment: ...and is pretty much unreadable.

Comment: I think Java is case-sensitive. Use `InputListener` and `addListener()`

Comment: @mbomb007 And `obj` not `Obj` too.

Comment: @mbomb007 And `class` not `Class`.

Comment: Sorry for the case errors in above code.i typed it on my smartphone.There are no compilation or case errors in my original code just the changed values dont reflect. And touchdown method gets called as i can see button actions are working.anyway i will cut paste the code soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for you time but I finally got the leakage and it was not related to any of the fundamentals but a human error. I had commented out the code to update the text that draws the instance on screen in bitmaptext form.
Debugged it using logcat and here is my finding
**You can change the instances in an anonymous class directly**
You dont need *this* keyword unless the name of instance is different ofcourse.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a few case errors. Typically, Java follows camel casing conventions. Secondly, because you are within an anonymous inner class you must specify which object you are referring to:

```
// inside the anonymous class 

classA.this.changeit = -2;
```